# Download multiple files without zip?

Tags: file-download

I want to download multiple files from a Sharepoint folder to my hard drive. When I select multiple files to download it automatically zips them but our IT dept does not allow zip files, so nothing happens. Same thing happens if I choose to download a folder. I can download each file individually no problem.

How can I download many files at once without zip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading two or more documents will place them into a zip file. You could sync the library using the Sync button in the command bar of the Document Library. Another option would be to use WebDAV/mapping the path.

[Sync SharePoint files with the OneDrive sync app](https://support.office.com/article/sync-sharepoint-files-with-the-onedrive-sync-app-6de9ede8-5b6e-4503-80b2-6190f3354a88)

Comment: Can you provide detail on the Sync functionality?

Comment: Added to my answer.